# Searching in PL/SQL /Oracle Forms

Tags: sql, algorithm, forms, plsql, oracle10g

This is with respect to search of a text in a table

Table_Name:
Details

Columns:
Fname,Mname,Lname,NName

This table contains nearly one lakh records

We are using Oracle forms for some querying option

The user input one name the form searches the table for the name and based on the name either(Fname/Mname/Lname/NName) in which column its is present further actions are proceeeded.

The search is taking a long time since we have huge amount of data present in the table.

I tried with Functional indexes for the table but t did not work its also taking more time

Later i tried with something like this 
concatenated all the names into one name and put it into a cursor.
Using the cursor output i tried with Instring but it is hanging

I also tried with searching for building a dynamic cursor but it did not work.

My database is Oracle

Can u help me to out to find an effective solution or please help me if i have missed something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, 1 lakh (100,000) records is not in itself a large table.

The problem I can see is the query appears to be doing an OR against the Fname/Mname/Lname/NName columns.
This means the query will be doing at least one full-table scan to obtain the results.
You may wish to use debug to obtain the query it is firing against the database and attempt to tune this at the SQL prompt using auto trace.

You may need to clarify if the search is also doing something like a LIKE against these columns rather than an EQUALS. As a LIKE will impact the query further and affect indexes.

Certainly the use of INSTR will disable indexes on your searched column.

It is not clear if what your block is based on ie. table, view, query, procedure

You may want to try using the hint on the block properties of the form FIRST_ROWS.

Comment: yes the search uses Like statement
 My block is based on a procedure inside the form
Yes i will try using the FIRST_ROWS and update if it helps me out